# Changing cell background in jtable, according to expiry dates

Tags: java, jframe, jtable

Currently I am trying to make an Expiry Date checker, whereby the user enters a Best Before Date of an item into a jtable. The program will output a red or green colored cell, according to whether it is expired by comparing it to the current date. 
Here is the code im working with: (for some reason no color changes occur)

```
    public void dateComparer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column){
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");     
     Calendar cal  = Calendar.getInstance();           
     String expDateString = sdf.format(cal.getTime());

     Date current = new Date(expDateString);
     Date BBD = new Date(jtableMain.getModel().getValueAt(row,3).toString());

     for(int i=0; i<=jtableMain.getRowCount()-1; i++){
         if(BBD.before(current))
            setBackground(Color.GREEN);
         if(BBD.after(current))
             setBackground(Color.RED);

   }
```

Here is what the current setup looks like [jtable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiFT3.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post your code! What happens when you run it? What do you want to happen instead? Any errors? Stack traces?

Comment: Ok I posted my code, currently it just adds the data into the jtable, however I want the cells in BBD which are above or below the expiry date to change color (red/green)

Comment: Shouldn't you use the loop index variable in the check somehow?